# FAILED 21 : Incorrect integer value:

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

when doing an sql query from phpmyadmin it works fine but with the script im using i get this error in my php file.

```
$updatequery = " INSERT INTO emailSave (email, score) VALUES ('$email', '$score') ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE score = '$score'";
```

the database doenst get updated and i get this error

```
FAILED 21 : Incorrect integer value: '' for column `id15151883_email`.`emailSave`.`score` at row 1
```

the table has 4 columns , id auto increment , email unique , score int and time timestamp

Comment: Looks like `$score` is potentially empty.

Comment: im using the same code with mamp doing it localy and it gets passed to the database just fine! right now im trying to make it live throught 000webhost

Comment: Then perhaps you have different versions of software or configs that mean that on the live server, an empty string is not converted automatically? Can't really say, but the error message is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, your $score is empty.

Speaking of, I hope it's sanitized.
Imagine $score being `0'; drop table emailSave;--`

Comment: i ve been checking it on my code!! but it does work on mamp! same code just different database passwords. score cant be empty since i run debug in unity and score is indeed incrementing! are you sure thats what it means? maybe i should look at it more

Comment: @stratosla: We cannot debug your whole project. You posted a small part of code, and asked for the meaning of the error message. You got it. $score is empty. You can try to find out why or ask another question about it, but denial won't work :-)

Comment: haha you are right! am gonna debug it more then! thank you!!